# troubleshooting purejavahidapi library openDevice function

Tags: java, hid

When trying to open a connection to my HID device it's giving a errno 13 on fedora 30

I've tried setting a udev rule and changing dev file ownership (I know it's a short term fix) none of which helped

I've tried contacting the purejavahidapi library creator, as far as they're concerned they're not a linux user so they don't know how to fix it and it's not a library related problem so look on the Internet to fix it

```
public static void setup ()
    {
        List<HidDeviceInfo> devList = PureJavaHidApi.enumerateDevices();
        for (HidDeviceInfo info : devList)
        {
            if (info.getProductString().contains("Reader"))
            {
                System.out.println("Product String: " + info.getProductString());
                readerDevice = info;
                break;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            System.out.println("ReaderDevice content: ");
            System.out.println(readerDevice.getProductString());
            HidDevice dev = PureJavaHidApi.openDevice(readerDevice);

            dev.setInputReportListener(new InputReportListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onInputReport(HidDevice hd, byte b, byte[] reportData, int i) {
                    System.out.println(reportData.toString());
                }

            });
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Exception Encountered");
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

The expected result is that the program establishes a connection to the HID device, what it's actually giving me is

> java.io.IOException: open() failed, errno 13'

stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: open() failed, errno 13
    at purejavahidapi.linux.HidDevice.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at purejavahidapi.linux.LinuxBackend.openDevice(Unknown Source)
    at purejavahidapi.PureJavaHidApi.openDevice(Unknown Source)
    at rfid.project.RfidProject.setup(RfidProject.java:41)
    at rfid.project.RfidProject.main(RfidProject.java:22)
```

Comment: Add `ex.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` block and then post that stack trace.

Comment: I agree with the purejavahidapi library creator. This is a linux problem and not a java problem. The user that is running your java program can be obtained via `System` property _user.name_. Apparently that user has no permission to open the `readerDevice` and I guess you want permission to open that device, either with the current user you are trying or maybe with a different user. Nonetheless, there is nothing wrong with your java nor, apparently with the purejavahidapi library. I suggest you try posting a new [linux] question asking for help with permissions for reader devices.